# Analysing the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Need some help with the following question and I am not sure where to start:

> Analyse the convergence of the series in terms of $t$
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$

I am assuming I use some sort of positive series convergence test but I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{(n+1)!^2}{(2n+2)!}t^{2n+2}}{\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}t^{2n}}
&=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\,t^2\\
&=\frac14\frac{n+1}{n+1/2}\,t^2
\end{align}
$$
which tends to $\frac14t^2$.

Now apply the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Answer (score 1):

By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we have that the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) satisfies
$$
{2n \choose n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of the above power series is
$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}{2n \choose n}^{1/(2n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\right)^{1/(2n)}=2.$$
Can you take it from here? Is the series convergent when $t=2$ (or $t=-2$)?

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test states that a series $\sum_n a_n$ converges if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$

Using the ratio test, we have convergence if $t\in (-2,2)$, inconclusiveness if $t=\pm2$, and divergence otherwise.